# How do i get the errors and warning from browser console using selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

dc = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
dc['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=dc)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print(entry)
 
driver.quit()
```

I run the above code, but getting the below 2 errors  in pycharm

```
in _execute_child    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
in start    raise WebDriverException(selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it looks for the chrome webdriver executable, which you can find and download here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/
There are two solutions:

1. add the chrome executable path to your system PATH variables (for Windows: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html)
2. add chromedriver path manually in this line:
   `driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=dc, executable_path = PATH_TO_WEBDRIVER)`

Comment: Thanks .. Second option worked .Have a great day

Comment: have one more query: Will the below code applicable to whole application(having around 30 different pages) or i need to add this in each page. If so, which code i have to use in each page?

Answer (score 0):

I know a good practice: "import logger", but I will suggest a solution

```
import time
time_at_run_script=time.time()


driver.get('https://httpbin.org')
# ... code script ...

 
print([
    entry
        for entry in driver.get_log("browser")
            if entry["timestamp"] > time_at_run_script
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response to the query